# How to limit access to Azure Function App to a website and clients only

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, blazor

I have an API running on a Function App in Azure.

I want this API to only accept communications from two parties:

1. A blazor website
2. All copies of a piece of packaged software (a WPF application which will run on customer computers)

I want all other traffic to be rejected.

What is the best way to configure this networking scenario?

The ideal setup:

[image: Diagram of the setup]

API should only be able to talk to the Blazor App as well as the client programs, not outside connections. The API can talk to the database which **lays behind a virtual network**. This Database VNET is already set up.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#secure-an-http-endpoint-in-production

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks for the help, I guess I will create one managed identity for the blazor, and a second managed identity for the clients, and disallow any traffic that is not one of the two.

Comment: Just be aware that that would require sending the client secret along with the WPF app, from which it could be extracted and used from other clients.  To really be secure you would need to authenticate the application users.

Answer (score 0):

Use API Management in front of the API and require Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key in the requests.

Also, add ip restrictions to avoid unauthorized access

Comment: Okay, I have secured the API with a subscription key and added IP restrictions,, is that enough? Some people say that you should also use OAuth or something, but for internal operations like calling the API serverside, it should be basically impossible to guess no? I tested the key out and it said it would take 18 thousand trillion trillion years to guess that key, assuming its not an internal attack. So just keep the key secure and ensure no one can find out what it is? I made sure to make a second key with no tracing and i use that one